# Что такое пространственная сложность алгоритма?

Tags: алгоритм, терминология, сложность, space-complexity

Что такое пространственная сложность алгоритма?

Comment: А есть у этого термина каноническое английское название? А то на русском звучит непривычно ..

Comment: @KromStern На мой взгляд, это «space complexity».

Comment: @Kromster Что-то Вы в пуризм ударились. Может, тогда в тело вопроса (и других поправленных) английский вариант добавить, чтобы искать проще было (как вопрос здесь, так и доп. информацию по теме)?

Comment: @MBo просто на глаза попались. Вопросы хорошие, четкие, полезные. Если считаете нужным добавить - прошу! )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Пространственная сложность - это один из критериев оценки алгоритмов. Под ней понимается зависимость количества занимаемой памяти от размера входных данных.

Comment: Как обычно, под сложностью обычно понимается рост (дельта) при росте объема  данных, а не просто *"зависимость количества"*. Линейно, квадратно, и т.п. )